# EXT4 External HDD slow write speed

Tags: kodi, filesystem, hard-drive

After seeing all the benefits of using EXT4 as the filesystem of choice for external drives, I opted for it, and connected an external HDD to my Raspberry Pi, running XBMC.

I tend to get write speeds of 3-4MB/s for the first 2-3 seconds and then a steep decline in speed takes it down to around 300Kb/s.

Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

UPDATE: I ended up giving up on finding the bottleneck. Here's the solution I employed. Partitioned the external drive to fat32 and exFat and by default I get nice high write speeds from memory card to external drive on both counts. This means that I can handle files >4GB too.

Comment: Where is the source of the written data coming from?  Could the read be the bottleneck?

Comment: Definitely not the read....It's coming from the SD card on the Pi, class 10 16GB

Comment: Does `dmesg` show that the drive is connected to a "high speed" USB port?

Comment: Yes, it does show High Speed USB

Comment: Test the hard drive directly by using a benchmark on the HDD only. Possibly your SD card is the problem.

Comment: Tried the hardrive on OS X and Ubuntu for read and write, Speeds were normal, ~20Mb/s. I'll swap out the memory card and see if that helps. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Is the drive plugged directly into a USB port on the Pi?  I had an issue that was caused by the USB hub I was using.  I get 5 to 10 MB/s throughput on a USB drive connected to my Pi.